# ModernCV: How to change position of pic & section looking

Tags: moderncv, cv

I'm writing a CV at the moment and I have some special wishes for the appearance but I don't know how to get it with `moderncv` class.

My questions/wishes are:

1. In Austria the picture is still important but I would like to save space. Therefore I would like to have the pic at the right side. The personal information should be on the left of the pic. Like shown here: https://www.en.lebenslaufmuster.biz/img/lebenslauf002.jpg (only the personal information part of this example).

   My picture has the aspect ratio of around 1.6 (height/width) and should have a height of around 5 cm.
2. Is there a chance to get the appearance of the sections differently? I would like to have a coloured background like the green one in this picture: https://www.jobseeker.com/api/media/documents/78564517-63ba-4f77-a24b-6856d750b2e6/CV-template-Classic.1686651796314.svg

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.5cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name

% Remove the dot at the end of the line of CVentry
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[6]{%
    \cvline{#1}{%
        {\bfseries#2}%
        \ifx#3\else{, {\slshape#3}}\fi%
        \ifx#4\else{, #4}\fi%
        \ifx#5\else{, #5}\fi%
        \ifx#6\else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#6\end{minipage}}\fi
}}%

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{
    \@closing\\[2em]%
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image}
        \par
        \bfseries \@firstname~\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
        \\%
        \vfill%
        {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}
}

\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand\enclname{Anlagen}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{Dr. A. Maxime} % Your first name
\familyname{Schuster} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{Lebenslauf}
\address{Musterstraße 12}{12344 Hamburg}
\mobile{+49 (0)172 132 132}
%\phone{+49 (0)0443 134 134}
\email{Maxime.Schuster@gmail.com}
% \homepage{staff.org.edu/~jsmith}{staff.org.edu/$\sim$jsmith} % The first argument is the url for the clickable link, the second argument is the url displayed in the template - this allows special characters to be displayed such as the tilde in this example
%\extrainfo{additional information}

\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{example-image} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand\mybitem[1]{%
    \parbox[t]{3mm}{\textbullet}\parbox[t]{10cm}{#1}\\[1.6mm]}


\begin{document}
        %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   CURRICULUM VITAE
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \makecvtitle % Print the CV title
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   EDUCATION SECTION
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \section{Persönliche Daten}
    
    \cvitem{Name}{Aaron \underline{Maxime} Schuster}
    
    \cvitem{Adresse:}{Musterstraße 12, 12344 Hamburgs}
    
    \cvitem{Telefon:}{+49 (0)172 132 132}
    
    \cvitem{Staatsangehörigkeit:}{Deutsch}
    
    \cvitem{Geburtsdaten}{8. Juni 1993 in Hamburg}
    
    
    \section{Kernkompetenzen}
    
    
    
    
    \section{Berufserfahrung}
    
    %------------------------------------------------
    \cventry{ab 01/2023}{Wissenschaftlicher Mitarbeiter (PostDoc)}{Universität Hamburg}{}{}{%
        \mybitem{Entwicklung, Konstruktion und Anwendung von experimentellen UHV-Designs und Lösungen}}
        
    
    
    \cventry{10/2020 -- 12/2023}{Forschungen zur Elektronenstoßionisation}{Universität Hamburg}{}{}{%
        \mybitem{Konstruktion und Aufbau von Hochspannungsschränken}}
    
    \cventry{02/2015 -- 08/2019}{Tutor für Laborpraktika für Bsc-Physik-Studenten}{Universität Hamburg}{}{}{%
        \mybitem{Betreuung von jährlich ca. 100 Stundenten der Physik, Materialwissenschaften und Gymnasiallehramt}}
    
    
    \section{Ausbildung}
    

    
    \section{Doktorarbeit}
    

    
    \section{Masters Thesis}
    
    \cvitem{Supervisor}{Prof. Dr. Mustermann}
    \cvitem{Titel}{Fancy Titel}
    
    
    \section{Interessen}
    
    \renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~} % Changes the symbol used for lists
    
    \cvlistdoubleitem{Kochen}{Singen}
    \cvlistdoubleitem{Schreiben}{Lesen}
        
    
    \vspace{2cm}
    ~\\
    ~\\
    Hamburg, \today
    ~\\
    ~\\
    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image}
    ~\\
    {\bfseries Dr. Mustermann}
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Picture that illustrates my wishes hopefully more]

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot? May make some points more self-evident. Thank you

Comment: Sure, I have an edited picture here. Hope, it is more clear now? The green frame stands for personal informations and the picture in one line but without a frame.

Comment: When you check /tex/latex/moderncv in your installation, you'll see a kind of modular system. E.g. viewing the styles for banking, casual, classic, they use different head/body/foot modules. The manual is rather short in this aspect. While you could place your image in a section, it's quite obscure how to modify or impact header and footer: a few renewcommands probably won't do the job. So best thing may be to contact the mantainer: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv . (Perhaps somebody else can assist here). Best wishes

Comment: It would be great if there is someone else here who can assist. There is a bit time pressure :-)

Comment: If it doesn't have to be exactly this documentclass, there is hardly any obsticle to reproduce it e.g. by using fancyhdr, xcolor, flushleft/flushright environment, \rule and a table without any rules for the layout.

Comment: No, the class is not mandatory. It was my first approach because I thought it is easier.